# A curious function in a PHP framework Slim

Tags: php, slim

The following function `normalizeKey`, input `$key`, return `$key`, how does `$key` be transformed from sting to mixed?

```
namespace Slim\Helper;

class Set implements \ArrayAccess, \Countable, \IteratorAggregate
{
    ....

    /**
     * Normalize data key
     *
     * Used to transform data key into the necessary
     * key format for this set. Used in subclasses
     * like \Slim\Http\Headers.
     *
     * @param  string $key The data key
     * @return mixed       The transformed/normalized data key
     */
    protected function normalizeKey($key)
    {
        return $key;
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: `$key` is maybe not a string but also mixed, the comments might simply be wrong

Comment: Per the comments in the function, it's there for subclasses to override it.

Comment: You shouldn't watch this base declaration but the override. I think this is just a declaration on how the method should works. If you check normalizeKey() in \slim\http\headers you will see a clear implementation.